# Ignore reference function argument

Tags: c++, c++11, parameter-passing

I have function with this signature (I can not edit it):

```
void foo(int a,int b, int& c);
```

I want to call it but I do not care about the getting c. Currently I do this:

```
int temp;
foo(5,4,temp);
//temp never used again
```

My solution seems dumb. What is the standard way to ignore this argument.

Comment: Write an overloaded wrapper function with only the two first arguments?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is **none**.

If your main concern is about polluting the current stack with a temp variable, a wrapper function like this should suffice:

```
void foo_wrapper(int a, int b)
{
    int temp; foo(a, b, temp);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would write an overload that turns the output argument into a normal return value. I really don't like output arguments and think that they should be avoided.

```
int foo(int a, int b) {
    int tmp = 0;
    foo(a,b, tmp);
    return tmp;
}
```

In your program, you just this overload and either ignore the return value or use it.

Answer (score 1):

This is an over engineered solution, so I don't actually recommend it as the first option in production code.

You can create a class to help you easily ignore these kinds of arguments:

```
template <class T>
struct RefIgnore
{
    static inline T ignored_{};

    constexpr operator T&() const
    {
        return ignored_;
    }
};

template <class T>
constexpr RefIgnore<T> ref_ignore{};
```

```
void foo(int a,int b, int& c);

auto test()
{
    foo(2, 3, ref_ignore<int>);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you recommend using it? When somebody reads the code, the intentions are quite clear. It's not like the usage of ref_ignore is obfuscating anything. Also using it requires less work than creating an overload function.

Answer (score -3):

Instead of reference you can pass it as a pointer

`void foo(int a,int b, int *c = NULL);`

in calling place you can either have it as

`foo(5, 6);`

or if you want to pass the 3rd argument then you can have it as

`int n = 3;
foo (1, 2, &n);`

Comment: You didn't read the part that says that the signature can't be changed.